# Excel - Sum Across Multiple Sheets Using INDIRECT

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a calculation as follows below which is hardcoded (though works), but I want to be able to use the INDIRECT() function to feed it - to avoid needing to change multiple formula in the workbook.

```
=SUM('Person 1:Person 8'!A1:D20)
```

I'd like to be able to enter 'Person 1' in say cell B2, and 'Person 8' in say cell B3, meaning I could write a formula like below to generalise the workbook, but it evaluates as #REF!.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&B2&":"&B3&"'!A1:D20"))
```

What would be the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: when you say, `it evaluates incorrectly` can you be more specific as to the error?

Comment: Thanks. Just changed the question now - it evaluates as '#REF!'.

Comment: if the concatenated string - which you feed to `INDIRECT()` gives a correct "link", and you still get an error; then you have a formula or result exception or error elsewhere than in the `INDIRECT()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use SUMIF and SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&B2:B3&"'!"&"A1:D20"),"<>"))
```

Comment: Thank you, though this seems to evaluate a different number to the hardcode (which I've confirmed makes sense) when I enter my variables. Might you be able to hazard a guess why?

Comment: this is only looking at the two sheets, did you want everything between the sheets?  The "hardcode" version will sum all the sheets between those two.

Comment: Yeah, or alternatively how I could pass in a list / named range of sheets into the formula would work great too. So - in my version - Person A and B are really Person 1 and Person 8, and I want to encompass the names inbetween too.

Comment: you will need to generate the list of sheets desired.  Then refer to that range.  Or you will need VBA to return an array of sheet names.  This cannot be done with formula alone.

Comment: Yeah so I've already got a list of the names - in my version contained in cells M2:M9. How can I pass that information into the formula you originally wrote?

Comment: replace `B2:B3` with `M2:M9`

Comment: Realize that if the cells contain anything but an exact match to a sheet name this will throw an error.

Comment: That works ideal. Thank you.

Comment: Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: One quick question, is it really `Person #` as the sheet name?  if so we can do some more magic to use a starting number and ending number to get the sheets.

Comment: No, it's actually their real names - but I'm going to attempt now to count the number of items in the list such that the M2:MX is generalisable, and you can just tack more stuff on the bottom

Comment: I would use a structured table then you can refer to the column and it will grow or shrink based on the table size.

Comment: Yeah my attempt hasn't worked; how can I change say that 'M9' termination to being 'M{the value in B4}'?

Comment: Try `M2:INDEX(M:M,B4)` or `INDEX(M:M,B3):INDEX(M:M,B4)` where `B3` is the first Row and `B4` the last desired.

Comment: Got it via the table suggestion - cheers. All functioning.